# Programming tutorials for WebLogic portal

Tags: weblogic

Hi

Are there any beginner tutorials for learning WebLogic portal?

I just installed the application and just trying to play around with it.

Answer (score 2):

Oracle have an application developer tutorial for each version which should be good to start with. See those first and you should ask a more specific question if you need to.

[v 10.3 i.e. 11g](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E13155_01/wlp/docs103/tutorials/index.html)

[v 9.2](http://download-llnw.oracle.com/docs/cd/E13218_01/wlp/docs92/tutorials/index.html)